# Windows Universal App SQLlite in Portable DLL

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

My project structure is defined like this:

- LIB Com basic communication, (requests and responses)
- LIB Com.BackgroundTask background task that will fetch new messages from server
- LIB Com.Mediator background logic that will handle every exchange of information and interaction between Com and the ViewModel
- LIB Model all Models for the Project, also the Databases should be defined here.
- LIB Settings App settings.
- Windows App Views/Controls for Windows
- Windows Phone App Views/Controls for Windows Phone
- Shared Basic App logic, Mediator init, ViewModels

the Problem is that you cannot reference the SQLLite extension in the (Portable) LIB Model but this is essentialy for the project structure to work. Otherwise the BackgroundTask would never be able to update the Database, am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer SQLite in a portable class library project using [Portable Class Library for SQLite](https://sqlitepcl.codeplex.com/). This project has been initiated by Microsoft Open Technologies, Inc. working with the community.

> This portable class library for SQLite available as NuGet package
>   simplifies the installation and development experience for .NET
>   developers by providing a single interface across Windows Phone,
>   Windows Store and .NET Framework 4.5.
>
> With this solution .NET developers can develop against one portable
>   class library and do not have to worry about what assembly is loaded.

**Drawback:** Targeting x64 platform architecture is not supported at the moment.

Targets supported: x86, and AnyCPU (with "Prefer 32-bit" option marked).

**Pre-requisites:**

1) The developer visits http://sqlite.org/download.html, and downloads the required precompiled binary for Windows v3.8.5 (http://sqlite.org/2014/sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3080500.zip), extracts the sqlite3.dll file, and adds it as Copy-Always Content to the root folder of the project.

2) In Visual Studio, the developer uses NuGet Packet Manager Console to install the SQLitePCL wrapper package.
Inside the Package Manager Console, type: Install-Package SQLitePCL

Comment: Ok I did it. But it is not that easy. Thank you.